# When are variables implicitly initialized in C++?

Tags: c++11, initialization

As of C++11, when are local variables automatically initialized

If I write

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

And then use v somewhere in the function, is automatically `v` initialized?

Comment: Yes, `v` is initialized by `std::vector<int>`'s default constructor. That's why it's called "default".

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object, it is initialized through a constructor. Every class can have an explicitly defined constructor, and, if no constructor is defined for a class, compiler automatically supplies a default constructor.

In the `std::vector` case, the defualt constructor of the class will be called, since you are not supplying any arguments.

Comment: Does this apply to primitives like ints?

Comment: Yes. They might have random values however. For example, `int i;` creates and allocates memory for an `int`. The particular value held in that variable at such a default initialization is compiler dependent.

Comment: The difference between incomplete types (like classes) and the primitive types like `int` is that the default constructor for the classes can be made to initialize the variable to specific values, i.e., it is "proper" initialization. But for the primitive types, the value held by them by simply defining them is not fixed. So this is not considered as "initialization" proper. But it can be used after definition like all other variables.